# Mixing ES6 Promises with JQuery Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, ecmascript-6

I have used $q (Angular.js) and would often return promises within a `.then` call. The effect was that the next `.then` call would wait for the previous promise to finish.

I am now using native es6 promises to try to 'promisify' a callback based library and I am unable to do so.

The problem is that the next value in the `.then` chain is a *promise object*, rather than the resolved value of that promise. It calls the next `.then` value before the promise is resolved, simply returning the last return value.

Is there anyway to wait for the previous promise to resolve?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//localhost:3000/api/tokens",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      user: {
        email: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'password123'
      }
    }),
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.then(data => data.token.encoded)         // OK
.then(token => Farmbot({ token: token })) // OK
.then(function(bot){                      // OK
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    bot.connect(function(){ resolve(bot); });
  });
}, errorr)
.then(function(bot){ // NOT OK!
  // passes in an unresolved promise object, which is useless.
  //
  bot; // => {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
});
```

My question is:

**Do ES6 promises wait for the previous `.then`'s promise to resolve?**

Comment: Angular and jQuery don't make particularly good bedfellows. In an angular app you should really be using `$http()`, not `jQuery.ajax()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue stems from trying to use a native `Promise` within a chain of [`Deferred` promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Currently (jQuery 1.8 – 2.x), jQuery's definition of [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) only recognizes the library's own type in its support for chaining.

So, you could return a `$.Deferred()` promise instead:

```
// ...
.then(function(bot){
  return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
    bot.connect(function(){ defer.resolve(bot); });
  });
}, errorr)
// ...
```

Or, you can use [`Promise.resolve(thenable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to convert the initial `$.Deferred()` given by `$.ajax()` to a native `Promise` so that you're using the native [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) throughout the chain, which will recognize a `new Promise()` being returned (as well as a `$.Deferred()`):

```
Promise.resolve($.ajax({
  // ...
}))
.then(data => data.token.encoded)
// ...
```

---

Or, you can try jQuery 3.0, [currently in beta](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/):

> **jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible**
>
> jQuery.Deferred objects have been updated for compatibility with Promises/A+ and ES2015 Promises, verified with the [Promises/A+ Compliance Test Suite](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests). [...]

With it, your original snippet should work as you expected without any revision.

Comment: In the second code , will `.then(() => req)` work ?  I mean `req` is still jquery's  type....

Comment: @RoyiNamir The native [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) will return a `new Promise()` and the method is defined to work with other "*thenables*," like Deferreds.

Comment: Well, found the extra `.then()` isn't really necessary. [*`Promise.resolve(thenable)`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) covers it. But, yeah, it appears to work well with both 3.0-beta1 (https://jsfiddle.net/694o4x32/) and 2.2.2 (https://jsfiddle.net/kuLbh12a/).

Answer (score 3):

> Do ES6 promises wait for the previous .then's promise to resolve?

Put it this way: an ES6 promise *never, ever* calls a `.then(onFulfilled)` function with a promise or thenable object. Onfulfilled listeners are only called with non-promise values.

Converting jQuery "thenable" objects into ES6 Promises before trusting them may solve the problem:

```
var jqPromise = $.ajax({
    url: "//localhost:3000/api/tokens",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      user: {
        email: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'password123'
      }
    }),
    contentType: "application/json"
})
.then(data => data.token.encoded)         // OK
.then(token => Farmbot({ token: token })) // OK

; 

var es6Promise = Promise.resolve(jqPromise); // convert to ES6 promise

es6Promise.then(function(bot){                      // OK
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    bot.connect(function(){ resolve(bot); });
  });
}, errorr)
.then(function(bot){ // will not pass in unfulfilled promise

  // process bot value

});
```